# Is it safe to use LoadLibrary to open dlls for analysis?

Tags: windows, dll

If I use LoadLibrary to dynamically load a DLL do I need to worry about any initialization code in the library being executed before control is returned to my code?

I want to perform an examination of suspicious DLLs to determine, for example, APIs used or entry points and I want to do it programmatically and not use a command line tool. Also I want to avoid running the application to see what happens ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: `LoadLibraryEx(name, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)`

Comment: Why the down vote without comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: no, it is not safe.

Calling `LoadLibrary`, will execute the DllMain in the library as well as initialize any global objects (which can execute constructors). It will also cause the loader to call LoadLibrary on an dependent DLLs as well.

To safely load the binary, you will want to just use normal file IO to parse the binary and do your static analysis.